# How can I select all paragraph elements inside nested divs?

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I have a reviews that I want to scrape (https://www.consumeraffairs.com/insurance/bluecross_fl.html). The issue that I find is that some reviews aren't stored inside the same structure. In the page you have to press "read full review" and this access another part of the structure that contains the remaining of the review.

The structure for simple reviews is like this:

```
<div>
   <p>
     review
   </p>
</div>
```

The other reviews structure is like this:

```
<div>
   <p>
     review
   </p>
   <div>
       <p>
         remaining review
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like this but still I'm just getting the first part of the reviews and not the remaining.

`response.css('itemprop="reviews"] > div:nth-child(3) > p *::text').extract()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the general [child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) you should be able to target all of the `p`'s in divs. Despite the structure.

```css
div > p {
  background-color: #ffd110;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    review
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      remaining review
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    review
  </p>
</div>
```

**Edit ~** From requested in the comments, you can concentrate which `p` gets selected using `p:nth-child(2)` See below.

```css
div > p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ffd110;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    review
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      remaining review
    </p>
    <p>review 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works!!! Is there a way to concatenate the results in case of a remaining review appears directly? I can do it with a external indexing but I don't know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: @JorgeRamos Yes! See edits.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it